# Snowflake Azure AD oAuth

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In the process of setting Azure AD oAuth2 for Snowflake, not successful in getting tokens yet. Followed these two document to set up this, https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/External-oAuth-Token-Generation-using-Azure-AD and https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/oauth-azure.html#configure-microsoft-azure-ad-for-external-oauth

In community document, it was mentioned that Application URI needs to be changed from https://4353yyy2b-axxxx4-4b86-xxxxa-xxxxx whereas in another documents it was mentioned as https://your.company.com/4353yyy2b-axxxx4-4b86-xxxxa-xxxxx

Is this cause any issues? It should be good as long as correct scope is supplied when getting token.

Also, noticed that permissions described (step 13) in this document are for testing purpose https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/oauth-azure.html#step-2-create-an-oauth-client-in-azure-ad

Can someone share instructions that can be used for production environments? Thank you